# Snap gameObject to grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, mouse

I'm making a 2D TD game and currently I have made using quill18 tutorials a simple building system. However I'm trying to have it snap on my tiles as I mouse over them.

This is my script applied to the building object

```
    void Update(){
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    mousePos.z = 0;
    Vector2 mp = mousePos;
    this.transform.position = mousePos;

    Collider2D col = GetComponent<Collider2D> ();

    if (GameManager.instance.player.CanAffordCurrentBuilding()
        && !col.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("NonBuildingLayer"))
        && col.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("BuildingLayer"))
        && !col.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("BlockingLayer"))) {
        SpriteRenderer[] sprites = GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        foreach(SpriteRenderer sr in sprites)
            sr .color = Color.green;
        canPlace = true;
    } 
    else {
        SpriteRenderer[] sprites = GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        foreach(SpriteRenderer sr in sprites)
            sr .color = Color.red;
        canPlace = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && canPlace) {
        SpriteRenderer[] sprites = GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        foreach(SpriteRenderer sr in sprites)
            sr .color = Color.white;
        Destroy(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() );
        Destroy(this);
        GameManager.instance.player.BuildingWasPlaced();

    }
```

What this does is that if touching layer is "BuildingLayer" I will be able to place the object and the object is always following my mouse until I place it. However I want it to only follow my mouse when the touching layer is not BuildingLayer. And when the touching layer is BuildingLayer I want it to snap onto the tile that are closest to the mouse that is building layer. And continuously change snapping tile when I move around the mouse.

How could I accomplish something like this?
I have a list called grid that contains all the building tiles in the game if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what you could do is add trigger collision boxes to your buildings.
If you are going to drag one, make that one you are dragging have a slightly bigger trigger collision box.
Than check if there is a trigger collision on the object your dragging, if so, snap to a position relative to the object the collision is with. You'd need to check whether the collision is on the bottom, left, top or right.